# GameServerQuery output?

Tags: php, extract

This is the example  file

```
<?php 
include 'GameServerQuery.php'; 

echo '<pre>'; 

var_dump(GameServerQuery::querySource('178.33.129.216', 27022)); 



echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This is a part of Game Server Query file

```
    public static function querySource($host, $port) 
    { 
        if ($reponse = self::ping($host, $port, "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFTSource Engine Query")) { 

            $cs15 = false; 
            $info = array(); 
            $header = substr($reponse, 0, 5); 

            if ($header !== "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x6D" && $header !== "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x49") { 
                return false; 
            } 

            if ($reponse[4] == 'm') { //Le moteur CS1.5 
                $reponse = substr($reponse, 5); 
                $reponse = strstr($reponse, chr(0)); 
                $cs15 = true; 
            } 
            elseif ($reponse[4] == 'I') { // Le moteur source 
                $reponse = substr($reponse, 5); 
            } 
            else { 
                return false; 
            } 

            $info['version']        = self::getByte($reponse); 
            $info['name']            = trim(self::getString($reponse)); 
            $info['mapname']        = self::getString($reponse); 
            $info['gamedir']        = self::getString($reponse); 
            $info['gamedesc']        = self::getString($reponse); 
            if (!$cs15) $reponse = substr($reponse, 2); 
            $info['numplayers']    = self::getByte($reponse); 
            $info['maxplayers']    = self::getByte($reponse); 
            $info['bot']            = self::getByte($reponse); 
            $info['dedicated']    = (chr(self::getByte($reponse)) === 'd') ? 1 : 0; 
            $info['os']                = chr(self::getByte($reponse)); 
            $info['password']        = self::getByte($reponse); 
            $info['secure']        = self::getByte($reponse); 

            return $info; 
        } 

        return false; 
    }
```

And My Output is

```
    array(12) {
      ["version"]=>
      int(0)
      ["name"]=>
      string(28) "xGamers Winter Tournament #1"
      ["mapname"]=>
      string(8) "de_dust2"
      ["gamedir"]=>
      string(7) "cstrike"
      ["gamedesc"]=>
      string(10) "Server ~ 1"
      ["numplayers"]=>
      int(0)
      ["maxplayers"]=>
      int(16)
      ["bot"]=>
      int(47)
      ["dedicated"]=>
      int(1)
      ["os"]=>
      string(1) "l"
      ["password"]=>
      int(0)
      ["secure"]=>
      int(1)
    }
```

My question is ? Is there a way for me to get an output of these results in a way that I want for example.

```
    MaxPlayers: 16
    numPlayers: 0
    Name: "xGamers Winter Tournament #1"
```

Your help would be appreciated, im not so good at php but learning php is one of my life goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `var_dump` on on array, you can extract directly:

```
<?php
    $array = GameServerQuery::querySource('178.33.129.216', 27022);
    echo 'Name: '.$array['name'].'<br />';
    echo 'numPlayers: '.$array['numplayers'];
    /* etc ..... */
?>
```

or loop that array:

```
<?php
    $array = GameServerQuery::querySource('178.33.129.216', 27022);
    foreach($array as $key => $arg){
        echo $key.': '.$arg.'<br />';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Glad you understood :)

Comment: Another question?
Is there a way that I can replace the hostname and the port with some values fetched from the database for example $ipaddress    and $port ?
I tried but the function did not recognize it

Comment: Ask another question for this with what you tried :)

Comment: $array = GameServerQuery::querySource('178.33.129.216', 27022);
You see i have many server ip addresses in my database and i want to replace this ip 178.33.129.216 and the port 27022 with some data fetched from my database.
I already have the database and the tables fixed. the only thing i need right now is a way to output the gameserverqueries for each user.

Comment: No, I meant .. you should create a new question not comment here.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to output the example on your page, you need to make a little output template. This should work:

```
$data = GameServerQuery::querySource('178.33.129.216', 27022);

echo 'MaxPlayers: ' . $data['maxplayers'] . '<br />';
echo 'numPlayers: ' . $data['numplayers'] . '<br />';
echo 'Name: ' . $data['name'] . '<br />';
```

Make sure you get rid of the  tag though.

Comment: The other guy commented faster, anyway thankyou I really appreciate it